# Add alternating string by group in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame formatted like so:

| GameId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |

I want to create a new column called 'colour' which adds alternating rows with the colours white, black. I want this to reset for a new game Id and always begin with white so that it is formatted like so:

| GameId | colour |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | white |
| 1 | black |
| 1 | white |
| 2 | white |
| 2 | black |
| 3 | white |
| 3 | black |
| 3 | white |

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could group by 'GameId' and create the 'colour' by `rep`licating a vector of values and specifying the `length.out` as the group length (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(GameId) %>%
    mutate(colour = rep(c("white", "black"), length.out = n())) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  GameId colour
   <int> <chr> 
1      1 white 
2      1 black 
3      1 white 
4      2 white 
5      2 black 
6      3 white 
7      3 black 
8      3 white
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GameId = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: That’s very neat

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` way

```
df$colour <- unlist(lapply(unique(df$GameId) ,\(x) rep(c("white", "black") ,
             length.out = sum(x == df$GameId))))
```

- output

```
  GameId colour
1      1  white
2      1  black
3      1  white
4      2  white
5      2  black
6      3  white
7      3  black
8      3  white
```